# Flask: pass argument to another route

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm making a app in what I need upload a file and work with it. I can upload successfully, but when I redirect, I can't pass the file (like a argument). The file is [global objects](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g).

```
@app.route('/analysis', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = getattr(g, 'file', None)
        file = g.file = request.files['file']
        return redirect(url_for('experiment'))
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/experiment', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def experiment():
    file = g.get('file', None)
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #do something with the file
        return render_template('experiment.html', data = data)
    else:
        return render_template('experiment.html')
```

This give this error:

```
AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `g` does not have a method called `get`, so that won't work. You are looking for `getattr`:

```
file = getattr(g, 'file', None)
```

Second, `g` is created at the beginning of each request and torn down at the end of each request.  Setting `g.file` at the end of one request (right before it is torn down) will not make `g.file` available at the beginning of another.

The right way to do this is either to:

- Store the file on the file-system (using a uuid for a name, for example) and pass the file's  uuid to the other endpoint:

  ```
  @app.route("/analyze", methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def analyze():
      if request.method == "POST":
          f = request.files['file']
          uuid = generate_unique_id()
          f.save("some/file/path/{}".format(uuid))
          return redirect(url_for("experiment", uuid=uuid))

  @app.route("/experiment/<uuid>")
  def experiment(uuid):
      with open("some/file/path/{}".format(uuid), "r") as f:
          # Do something with file here
  ```
- Move the code from `experiment` into `analyze`